# How do I Goto Anything (across all "projects" or windows) in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

**aka: How can I find a tab in another window in Sublime?**

In Sublime, the feature called *Goto Anything* (⌘+P, ⌘+T, Win: ⌃+P, etc.) searches through a list of open files/tabs, or any files (and more) but only in your current project/focused window :( I understand why it works that way but it's not super useful for having a bunch of random files open.

I'm currently using Sublime on my home computer (Mac) where I have 3 or 4 windows open (not technically *projects*, but Sublime seems to associate the two conceptually) each with 1-5 tabs. It's often difficult to find a tab I was using for a quick note (eg. groceries) because right-clicking the app icon in the dock only shows the active tab per window. If "groceries" was in a window and wasn't the last viewed tab when I went to another Sublime window, it's effectively lost, and I've got to start going through each one of my Sublime windows to find it.

I've also tried the *Find in Files...* feature (⇧+⌘+F) with `<open files>` in the *Where* field thinking I'd just search for something in the file (eg. eggs) but "open files" really means "open files in this project/window"...same scope limitation.

I've even looked for a plugins that might help but "Goto absolutely everything" is a concept that's hard to search for. I've been wanting to try writing my own so I'd be grateful for a Python solution as well!

Comment: Well, I chased the rabbit down the hole and discovered that Sublime's `window.focus_view(view)` doesn't work on a Mac to bring a different window into focus. The relevant forum post is [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6550). I spent far too long trying to write a plugin that searches all tabs across all windows only to fail at the very last method call I needed.

Comment: As a consolation prize, while trying to open the Sublime console, I accidentally discovered `⌘+\`` (Command+Backtick) which cycles through the current app's windows (on a Mac obviously.) That makes "manually" searching 50% better. That fun feature is discussed on [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50756/where-did-the-command-backtick-keyboard-shortcut-go-in-10-7-lion).

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a somewhat old thread, and you may have already come up with a solution. While there is no way that I know of to do a search or goto anything across all windows, I developed a Sublime Text plugin that allows you to jump between windows using `command+shift+o` on Mac OS X.

You can install it from package control:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GotoWindow

Comment: Doesn't work with projects in another space :(It finds them, just doesn't switch spaces.

Comment: You are honestly the best.